# What do 「はな」 and 「いうとな」 mean?

Tags: words

Here is the sentence including the words.

> このおっさん**はな**更{こう}生{せい}だとか　なんだとか　そんな　しゃれたことを考{かんが}えるようなおやじじゃねえよ
>
> まあ　ごくかんたんに**いうとな**

Another question: Do the 「な」 in both words work as particle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's この おっさん-は な and いう-と な, i.e. particle は or particle と followed by interjectional particle な, which functions as a filler in this case.