# Usage of な in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, nouns, particle-な

What is the meaning of な in the following sentence?

> この動画に映り込んでる背景は僕の家**な**気がする。

Is it an abbreviation of なんて or なんか? Or is it simply a filler as explained in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28006/17797)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, you can replace 「な気がする」 by 「である気がする」.

→ "I have the feeling that this video's background is my house"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide more details? Is this a common usage of な?

Comment: @Marco You can look up "na_adjective" or "attributive form of copula".